# PHP zip file upload does not work

Tags: php, html, upload, download, zip

My html form:

```
<form action='' method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file" id="file">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

My php file:

```
if ($_POST['submit'] == "Submit") {
            echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
            echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
            echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
            echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";
            if (file_exists("/downloads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
            {
                echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
            }
            else
            {
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
                "/downloads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
                echo "Stored in: " . "/downloads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
            }
}
```

there are 2 folders in my public_html: `tmp` and `downloads`, both 777 permissions (just to test)

this file is located in a .htaccess protected folder within downloads (public_html/downloads/new/update.php)
and i want the zip files to be uploaded in the downloads dir.

This code won't give me any errors, but does not upload the file. Why?

Comment: horrible code. you're assuming the upload succeeded. you use user-provided filenames directly in fileystem operations (malicious users can now scribble ANYWHERE on your server), and you simply assume the move operation succeeds.

Comment: The problem is '"/downloads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]' which has been already posted as an answer

Comment: don't worry about the security because this file is in a protected dir which only i can access...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how i solved it:

HTML:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="300000" />
<input type="file" name="file" id="file">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

PHP:

```
if($_POST['submit'] == "Submit") {
    $filename = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    $source = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
    $type = $_FILES["file"]["type"];
    $name = explode(".", $filename);
    $target_path = "../".$filename;
    if(move_uploaded_file($source, $target_path)) {
        $message = "Your .zip file was uploaded";
    } else {    
        $message = "ERROR";
    }
        if($message) echo $message;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding

```
if(move_uploaded_file(...)){
 echo "it works";
} else {
 echo "NOPE";
}
```

And
replace:

```
 move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "/downloads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

with:

```
 move_uploaded_file($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/'.$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/downloads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP needs MAX_FILE_SIZE to receive uploaded files

```
<form action='' method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="10240000">
<input type="file" name="file" id="file">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

with this form you can upload a zip archiv with 10 MB or less...

you must also set the max_post_size and upload_max_filesize in your php.ini to the same or a higher value to upload files

use this PHP code

```
if ((isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] == "Submit") AND isset($_FILES)) {
        echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
        echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
        echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
        echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";
        if (file_exists("/downloads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
        {
            echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
        }
        else
        {
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
            "/downloads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
                   echo "Stored in: " . "/downloads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];

            else echo "file could not be processed";
        }
```

}